# Absolute position and overflow:auto without a scroll bar appearing

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-position

I don't know if this is possible with only html and css, but I have an absolute div inside a relative container and want to have a regular div under the container.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="content">
    </div>

</div>

<div id="footer">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{


position:relative;
overflow:auto;



}

#content{

position:absolute;
width:955px;
z-index:1000;


}
```

The goal is to prevent the "content" div from overlapping into the footer. It worked with overflow:auto, but I got another vertical scrollbar appearing for the container div.

Any other ways to get around this?

Comment: how about 'overflow:hidden;'? is that what you are looking for?

Comment: no sorry, the content will be cut off if it is set to hidden. I need it to expand without a scroll appearing on the relative div.

Comment: I just want to understand it, why would you want content to visually block your view of the footer?

Comment: I want the footer to be BELOW the absolute positioned content, not blocked by it. My goal was to prevent the content from overlapping into the footer. I did that, but now my wrapper has a scrollbar. I need the content to expand vertically and also push the footer down when it does

Answer (score 1):

So, how about hiding only vertical scrollbar:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

?

If you're looking for something more fancy to hide scrollbars then you could use JavaScript mousescroll event to do it.
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/08/javascript-mouse-scroll-event-down-example.html
Or you could use some jquery plugin to handle scrollbars, there are plenty of them, jScrollpane, Scrollable...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this with only HTML and CSS. You may find the setup of the HTML and CSS code from http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ useful since it is using the same layout as your code and it trying to achieve a similar goal.

I have combined the code used to create a sticky footer with your code in the Fiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/bPybY/1/

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change the layout differently since element with `absolute` position doesn't have a layout space. Like this:

```
<html> 
<head>
<style>
#container{
position:relative;
}
#absoluteContent{
position:absolute;
width:955px;
z-index:1000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="absoluteContent">
    <div id="content">content
    </div>
    <div id="footer">footer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```